# How to send an email with content from a View  in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, php

I want to send an email to user from my application  with the content of the email loaded from a  *view*  . This is the code i've tried out till now:

```
$toemail = "user@email.id";

$subject = "Mail Subject is here";
$mesg = $this->load->view('template/email');

$this->load->library('email');

$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->to($toemail);
$this->email->from($fromemail, "Title");
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($mesg);
$mail = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Why do you want to send the mail from the view. You can get the data in a controller ( from a form , which can be in a view    or from database) .

Comment: "I want to" is not a question.

Comment: my question is "How to send an email with content from a View in codeigniter" see "I want to" is my question description so

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. You **need to**  call `$this->load->library('email');` within the controller  as well for the email in CI to work.
2. Also , in your code :  `$fromemail` is not initialized.
3. You need to have **SMTP support** on your server.
4. $config should be declared as an array *before* assigning values and keys.

Working Code:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$fromemail="ad@c.com";
$toemail = "user@email.id";
$subject = "Mail Subject is here";
$data=array();
// $mesg = $this->load->view('template/email',$data,true);
// or
$mesg = $this->load->view('template/email','',true);


$config=array(
'charset'=>'utf-8',
'wordwrap'=> TRUE,
'mailtype' => 'html'
);

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->to($toemail);
$this->email->from($fromemail, "Title");
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($mesg);
$mail = $this->email->send();
```

**Edit:**
    `$mesg = $this->load->view('template/email',true);` should be having the *true* as pointed out by lycanian. By setting it as true , it doesn't send data to the output stream but it will return as a string.

**Edit:**
`$this->load->view();` need a second parameter with data or empty like `$mesg = $this->load->view(view,data,true);`, if not it wont work

Comment: this is works:  $mesg = $this->load->view('payment/step1', '', TRUE);

Comment: @lycanian  otherwise it echo's. Thanks.

Comment: @lycanian Everything else is fine?.  Accept this as solution if the code is working.

Comment: Is this really necessary to load the library `$this->load->library('email');` twice?

Comment: how to do this `$mesg = $this->load->view('template/email','',true);` in Codeigniter 4?

Answer (score 9):

This line **$mesg = $this->load->view('template/email',true);** should be like this
 
**$mesg = $this->load->view('template/email','',true);**
with the single quotes before the value true, and it will work perfectly

Comment: This should be the excepted answer to the question http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 4):

Email template send In codeigniter we need to put and meta tag before sending email

```
$this->data['data'] = $data;
$message = $this->load->view('emailer/create-account', $this->data,  TRUE);
$this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
$this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
$this->email->from($email, $name);
$this->email->to('emailaddres@mail.com');
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

U will try it!! it's working for mine after many errors facing

```
            $subject = 'New message.';
            $config = Array(        
                'protocol' => 'sendmail',
                'smtp_host' => 'Your smtp host',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'webmail',
                'smtp_pass' => 'webmail pass',
                'smtp_timeout' => '4',
                'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                'charset'   => 'utf-8',
                'wordwrap' => TRUE
            );
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
            $this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');

            $this->email->from('from mail address', 'Company name ');
            $data = array(
                 'message'=> $this->input->post('message')
                     );
            $this->email->to($toEmail);  
            $this->email->subject($subject); 

            $body = $this->load->view('email/sendmail.php',$data,TRUE);
            $this->email->message($body);   
            $this->email->send();
```