# codeigniter mail() from view

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a contact page. By using ajax i call the contact action as

```
function contact_action() {

var form = $('#contact-form');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        url: '<?php echo site_url('user/contactaction');?>',
        success: function(msg){

                alert(msg);

        }
    });
            return false;


     }
```

In my user controller i have the follwoing function as

```
public function contactaction()
    {

        $this->load->view('frontend/contactaction');
    }
```

In contact action view file i have the code as

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

From here how to call the email(). I have referred this [How to send an email with content from a View  in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663277/how-to-send-an-email-with-content-from-a-view-in-codeigniter)

But i couldn't implement this in view. please help me

Comment: This is the error: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$email

Filename: frontend/contactaction.php
 Fatal error: Call to a member function initialize() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\hotel-codeign\app\views\frontend\contactaction.php on line 29

Comment: What if you work around in the controller any reason to involve the `view`

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the view? You should do it in the controller. Doing it in the view makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AJAX in this case, you need to write AJAX in the View, and call with AJAX a controller method (like you did), But in this method (in your case named contactaction) you need to get with post (I prefer json Type Data), send an email, and return any number on successful AJAX function show the message (like you want to show).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC architecture then you should put the controller code in controller file and view code in view file. Calling email() function belongs to controller.

1. Put your ajax code in your view file.
2. Create send_email() function in your controller
3. From your ajax code call that send_email() function.
4. Process your data there and send email
5. If you are returning anything back, like a message, just return it and in you ajax code onsuccess: you can process the message and display how you want it.

Let me know if you have any questions.