# Loading a template into an email CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm having trouble sending a template email. I'm trying to load a template when sending the email (based on other suggestions i saw on this forum). It looks something like this.

```
// load Email Library 
    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $message = $this->load->view('template_email', $data, true);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->from($from);
    $this->email->cc($cc);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
    if (!$this->email->send())
    {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Email Sent";
    }
```

But i'm getting and error "Unable to load file ...."

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Does this file "template_email" exist in your views folder?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   $message = $this->load->view('email/report',TRUE);
```

This question could be a posible duplicate. Anyway maybe this link could help you. [How to send an email with content from a View  in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663277/how-to-send-an-email-with-content-from-a-view-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, i've tried different ways of pointing at the file including something like "email/report". I saw the other post but it didn't help. My issue is that the view file wont, load that is the error i'm getting, i think its something to do with a view being loaded inside another view...