# How to add variable in php read file

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am sending email with php email function with codeigniter.

For that i had created template file and using it with read file function,

```
$message = $this->input->post('reply_content');
$this->load->helper('file');
$newbody = read_file(base_url().'/uploads/template.php');
```

//Email send like below

```
$this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('y@2.com', 'X');
    $this->email->to($this->input->post('reply_to')); 

    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($newbody);    
    $this->email->cc($this->input->post('reply_cc'));
    $this->email->send();
```

template.php is my template file which is formatted html.
What i need is to have $message inside template.php, so when user send email, a variable value is included in email,

How can i add variable inside template then read and then send as email?

Answer (score 1):

You should use parsing as follows :

```
$from = $this->config->item('from_email_id');
$to = $this->input->post('userEmail');
$subject = 'Welcome';
$email_data= array(
        'first_name' =>$user_info->first_name,
        'last_name' =>$user_info->last_name,
        'numeric_code' => $user_info->numeric_code
        );
$msg_body = $this->parser->parse('templates/activate_account', $email_data ,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to load library `file` I believe that you know how to put data into view. Let's try this

```
$data['message']=$this->input->post('reply_content');

$newbody=$this->load->view('/uploads/template',$data,true);
```

Comment: i dont want to view it, but i need to read file store as string but in that string one variable value should be inserted and then send as email body.

Comment: remove that **echo** from my answer now you can get the template as string in on the variable $newbody

Comment: you can pass any data to your page template , that is why I put it as a view. And this will be the effective solution for your constrain

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663277/how-to-send-an-email-with-content-from-a-view-in-codeigniter