# Codeigniter-How can i email a Bootstrap html page using PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I am trying to send a bootstrap receipt produced using database values to an email address using PHP mail function. Can someone tell me how to do it? and correct way?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Not yet. Trying to get an idea how can i do it. then i will start

Comment: Do some research and try. If you will get an error then will help you.

Comment: already did. cant find anything

Comment: This may help you..!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663277/how-to-send-an-email-with-content-from-a-view-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you cant. email just receipt html css only. may this answer help you